# How to post a array of promises with angularjs to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

i am using promises with angular to post some data to a node server.

I am doing a  loop into array "rowSafeAgendamentos" and fill a promises array to post in a node server.

When the data are posted,I see  in server side that all posts has the last date "2017-09-29T06:00:00.000Z". Other Dates as "2017-08-29T06:00:00.000Z" are lost.

If I put a log in the for..loop, I can see that

```
promises.push(newpromise(mymodelo))
```

is inserting the dates into array correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 $scope.rowSafeAgendamentos=[
....
...
{"agdata":"2017-08-29T06:00:00.000Z","$$hashKey":"object:2276"},
{"agdata":"2017-09-29T06:00:00.000Z","$$hashKey":"object:2277"}]

    $scope.salvarescolhas=function(modelo){
          var promises=[]
          var mymodelo=angular.copy(modelo);
          delete mymodelo._id;
          var newpromise=function(data){
            return dataService.insertPacienteAgendamento(data)
          }
          for (var i=0; i<$scope.rowSafeAgendamentos.length;i++){
               var item=$scope.rowSafeAgendamentos[i];
               mymodelo.slot_dateInit=moment(new Date(item.agdata)).clone().seconds(0).milliseconds(0).toDate();
               promises.push(newpromise(mymodelo));
          }
          $q.all(promises).then( (response)=>{
                toaster.pop('success',"Os dados foram salvos!");
             }, (erro)=>{
                      console.log(erro);
                      if (erro.data.code=11000)
                        toaster.pop('info',"Paciente já existe!");
                      else toaster.pop('info',erro.data.errmsg); 

              })
      }
```

//markup

```
<div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label no-padding-right" for="paciente-telefone">
                             Telefone celular
                             </label>
                             <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                               <input name="extra.telefone" id="paciente-telefone" type="text" ui-br-phone-number 
                                ng-model="modelo.paciente.telcel" 
                                class="form-control">
                             </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                      <div class="vert-offset-top-1 col-sm-12">
                        <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" 
                            st-safe-src="rowSafeAgendamentos" st-table="rowAgendamentos" 
                            ng-show="rowAgendamentos.length>0">
                              <thead>
                              <tr><td colspan="2" class="text-center btn-info"><span class="text-center"><strong>Prévia</strong></span></td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Data</th>
                                  <th>Hora</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr ng-repeat="row in rowAgendamentos">
                                    <td>{{row.agdata|date:'dd.MM.y(EEE)'}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.agdata|date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                              <tfoot ng-show="rowSafeAgendamentos.length>10">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                                      <div class="paginacao_lateral" st-items-by-page="10" st-pagination=""></div>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-centered"  ng-show="rowAgendamentos.length>0">
                      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="button" ng-disabled="!modelo._id"
                           ng-click="salvarescolhas(modelo)" uib-tootip="Precisa ter um agendamento base, para poder clicar aqui.">
                           Salvar essas escolhas
                      </button>
                      <p ng-show="!modelo._id" class="help-block">Desabilitado. Precisa ter um agendamento base</p>
</div>
```

//service

```
angular.module("clinang").service('dataService', ['$http','config', function ($http,config) {
        this.insertPacienteAgendamento = function (clinica) {
            return $http.post(urlBase+'/agendamentosdepacientes', clinica);
        };
}]);
```

Comment: you're posting `mymodelo` with the line `promises.push(newpromise(mymodelo));`, not `scope.rowSafeAgendamentos`, can't tell what it is from your code.

Comment: Hi, mymodelo is a copy of my model binded to view. I updated the question  with the markup.

Comment: `mymodelo.slot_dateInit=` sets the `slot_dateInit` for `mymodelo` ... `mymodelo` is the **same** object for every call to `newpromise` - depending on what `dataService.insertPacienteAgendamento` does with `data`, it could very well end up just as you described ... all have the same (last) `slot_dateInit`

Comment: can you show the code for `dataService.insertPacienteAgendamento`

Comment: Hi, "dataService.insertPacienteAgendamento" is only a service to post a $http to node server

Comment: Right, but that's possibly where toe EASIEST fix is. I didn't ask for that code just to make conversation - maybe not ... to be honest I can't see why your code would behave that way ... since the `slot_dateInit` is only updated **after** the request was made

Comment: I think the the problem is not in dataService.insertPacienteAgendamento.

Comment: you are right - but your problem now doesn't make sense to me :p

Comment: My problem is that the array with dates posted to node server using promises all has the same date(the last from array). But in the loop,  filling  the promises I set different dates to each one. I expect different dates on server side.

Comment: I just solved it creating a new var mymodelo into for..loop. Thanks for all